# Regex - understand lookaround

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm reading this [article](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and I'm having some difficulties to understand this:

given the string `quit` and the regex `q(?=u)i` why the regex doesn't match?

the engine first find q and then look ahead to see if there is an u after the q right? Since is a positive lookahead this will be result in a positive assertion, but then I cannot understand what happen next.

Some clue could be(about lookarounds):

```
They do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.
```

Someone can help me to fully understand this?

Many thanks!

Comment: It doesn't consume char, it means that the "regex pointer" stays at the same position (i.e. after the `q`) and there're no `i` after the `q` so the regex doesn't match; QED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a lookaround targets a position in between characters, not a character itself.

If we read your regex as the 3 steps:

1. Match the character `q`
2. Ensure that the next character is a `u` (it is) - this matches the position where `u` is the next character
3. After the lookaround, ensure the next character is an `i` - it isn't, because you're still in the position where the next character is a `u`.

Lookarounds are usually used to find the start/end of a wildcard match, for example, if you wanted to match ONLY the part of the word after a `qu`, you could use a look-behind to find the start of a capture:

```
(?<=\bqu)
```

Then capture any character until the end of the word:

```
(?<=\bqu).*?\b
```

This would match things like:

```
quit => it
question => estion
quagmire => agmire
```

Notice, the look behind indicated the START of the match, without having to know what the first character of the match would be.